# entry vs. component

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

When speaking about tuples, I used to say and write "The number $a$ is the first component of the tuple $(a,b,c)$, and $c$ is its last component". This all went well until I had to speak about software components in the same text; the meaning of "component" got overloaded. A change is need, so I'm thinking about saying "entry" for a part of a tuple. How do sentences such as "The number $a$ is the first entry of the tuple $(a,b,c)$, and $c$ is its last entry" sound? Any arguments for/against using "entry" to denote a part of a tuple?

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: Seems OK as long as you don't need to talk about data entry.

Comment: That's the sense I had in mind, but if there's another sense then that could also cause a clash of terminology.

Comment: An alternative to "entry" is "element".  This is used e.g. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

Comment: That's one particular way to implement tuples using ordered pairs.  The ordered pairs, and for that matter the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, can also be implemented using sets.  I think you need to distinguish between the  tuple and its implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This is appropriate terminology, although one interpretation that may feel intuitive from a software perspective is to view each "component" of a tuple as the $i$th element in the tuple. Hence in $(a,b,c)$, $a$ is located as the 1st element of the tuple, $b$ the 2nd, and $c$ the third. This gives a very nice notational representation to a tuple as a vector. For example, if we define
$$v = (a,b,c),$$
We can state $v_1 = a,$ and thus rather than describing an item as the $i$th element, we can simply address $v_i$.